# What controls which user posts are visible via the Facebook Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm making requests like the following:

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/posts?access_token=TOKEN

When the TOKEN is from the Graph API Explorer (from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer logged in as my own user account), I see some posts for most users.

When the TOKEN is a user token for my own app and my own user account, resulting from the client-side flow[*], I see `{ "data": [] }` for almost everyone.

What could cause the difference? As far as I can tell, the two tokens were given the same permissions (I get identical returns from https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=TOKEN for the two tokens).

All I can think is that the users whose posts I'm looking for aren't users of my app, but perhaps everyone is magically a user of the API Explorer. But the info I want to see about them is visible to me, both on their user page and from Graph using the API Explorer token, so surely this can't be a security restriction: *I* can get a token that shows me the information I want, but my app can't. Hence:

- why aren't the posts visible to me when using my app?
- what do I do about it?
- our current theory is that the API explorer has special privileges to access public data, and other apps can't get that. Is this really the case, or is there something I could do with my app to view public data via `/posts`?

[*] Using the URL: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=manage_pages,read_stream,read_requests,user_location,user_activities&response_type=token

Comment: Are you sure that your app has the "read_stream" extended permission?

Comment: @NitzanTomer: https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions says that the user token for my app has `"installed": 1, "read_stream": 1, "read_requests": 1, "manage_pages": 1, "user_location": 1, "user_activities": 1`. Do I also need the user I'm querying to give me the `read_stream` permission? And if that's the difference, when did all those users give the Graph API Explorer that permission? I disbelieve that they all just so happen to be Facebook app developers who've used it.

Comment: No, the "read_stream" should let you get the posts of the friends of the logged in user. I just tested it myself in the explorer, I removed a test app I have and re-added with only the "read_stream" permission and I got the posts of my friends. Remember that it only works on friends of the current logged in user. I suggest that you use the the explorer with DELETE for the path "me/permissions" and then click the "Get Access Token" button again.

Comment: @NitzanTomer: These users aren't my friends. Neverthless, I can see things in their `/posts` connection using the Graph API Explorer token. So maybe the peculiar thing here isn't that my app's user token shows nothing, but that the API Explorer shows anything. What it shows is actually statuses, but I still want to understand the difference between it and my app.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are saying, I tested it myself and I get the same.
Here's what I think is going on, but it's just a guess.

From what I just tested, the data that comes back when using the graph explorer app is public data of the user, like new friends and public posts.
It's the same exact data I can see if I go to the profile of the user in facebook.

Why doesn't your app get that public data?
Well, facebook grant special privileges to certain apps, and in the case of the graph explorer, which is their app, it's not far fetched to think that they did just that.
To test the theory I removed all permissions I have for the graph explorer and tried to get the posts of a user which is not my friend, and indeed I got the same results.
When I tested it with "me/posts" I got my posts, and not just the public ones.
If you remove the permissions from your own app then even your posts will return with *data: []*.

Your app can only get the data for the logged in user and his friends.

Comment: Thanks for helping. If their explorer app has access to data that no app of mine ever will, then they've basically raised my hopes only to dash them, haven't they? :-( Still, at least it isn't a security hole by which people could access non-public data using the explorer.

Comment: The explorer tool is just to help you for development and so it lets you see what you as a logged in user can. The documentation is a better source for what you can do.